# How to create multiple buttons using loop in app.layout of dash using python?

Tags: button

i have a list and i wanted to create button for each element of the list.

I am trying to create buttons at one go by using for loop inside app.layout which doesn't seem to work. Kindly help me with this. The code is

```
import os
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart3D,Reference
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output , State
import time
import dash_table
from collections import deque
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import random

owner_list = ['apple','banana','jack','grapes','pear']

external_css = ["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css"]
external_js = ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js']
app = dash.Dash('export-data',
                external_scripts=external_js,
                external_stylesheets=external_css
                )
colors = {
    'text': '#0000A0'
}
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='TASKS_COMPLETION',
            style={
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'color': colors['text']
                  })
                     ]),


     for every_owner in owner_list:
         html.Button(every_owner, id=every_owner)

    ], className="container",style={'width':'98%','margin-left':5,'margin-right':5,'max-width':50000})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=4050)
```

The for loop used inside app.layout doesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a list of button, outside `app.layout`.

Later, assign this newly created list to children as in `html.Div(children=<list>)`.

This solved issue for me.

```
import os
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart3D,Reference
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output , State
import time
import dash_table
from collections import deque
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import random

owner_list = ['apple','banana','jack','grapes','pear']

external_css = ["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css"]
external_js = ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js']
app = dash.Dash('export-data',
                external_scripts=external_js,
                external_stylesheets=external_css
                )
colors = {
    'text': '#0000A0'
}

lst=[]
for every_owner in owner_list:
    lst.append(html.Button(every_owner, id=every_owner))

app.layout=html.Div(
    html.Div(lst)
    )

# app.layout = html.Div(
#     children=[
#     html.Div(
#         children=[
#             html.H1(
#                 children='TASKS_COMPLETION',
#                 style={
#                     'textAlign': 'center',
#                     'color': colors['text']
#                   },
#                 html.Div(
#                     children=lst
#                     )
#                 )
#             ]
#         )
#     ],
#     className="container",
#     style={'width':'98%','margin-left':5,'margin-right':5,'max-width':50000}
#     )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=4050)
```

Tried to tweek your code. It is having some alignment problem as the buttons created gets hidden behind the H1 tag. So I hid it and produced the result which is like this. Hope this answers your question.

[image]